# Why are MS Word regex backreference replacements out of order?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace

I want to replace all the single-spaced sentence separations with double-spaced sentence separations. To that end, I am running the following.

Find: . ([A-Z])

Replace: .  \1

The find works fine, but the replace results are bizarre. We go from "... early 2015. Generator..." to "...early 2015G.  enerator..." The backreference is being put in the wrong place.

I've tried other variations like

Find: (. )([A-Z])

Replace: \1 \2

And

Find: (. )([A-Z])

Replace: \1 \2

With similar results. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It’s rather spectacular it isn’t destroying everything. In most (all?) regex dialects, `.` is the wildcard character. If you want a literal `.`, use `\.`.

Comment: @DanielB That doesn't seem to be how Word operates.

Comment: Tested in Word 2013. It is working perfectly without flaw.

Comment: @DanielB Microsoft Word's equivalent of RegEx "." is "?".

Comment: I'm running 2016 with the latest updates.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't have Word 2016. I throw it out the window because of its many bugs. But please check the text direction. i.e. isn't the text marked as right-to-left?

Comment: @FleetCommand Where would that setting be?

Comment: Main ribbon, Home tab, Paragraph section. Right between "Increase Indent" and "Sort" buttons. Of course, if you don't see it, then there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the exact same thing [@Stephen](https://superuser.com/users/136129/stephen-collings) , all replaced variables would be placed at the start and all the rest comes after that (e.g. "ABC_\2-\1_DEF" would become "\1\2ABC_-_DEF".

Google wasn't of any help at all and after I while I noticed I was not experiencing it in all open documents. I scratched my head for the difference, till I noticed that that one particular document had 'Track Changes' switched on. Flicked it off and the search and replace worked flawless as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).